# How to use flask-restplus's fields.Url for mongoengine Document queryset?

Tags: python, flask, marshalling, mongoengine, flask-restplus

I have the following Mongoengine `Document`:

```
class Post(mongo_db.Document):
    id = mongo_db.UUIDField(max_length=300, required=True, primary_key=True)
    content = mongo_db.StringField(max_length=300, required=False,)
    notes = mongo_db.ListField(mongo_db.StringField(max_length=2000), required=False)
    category = mongo_db.ReferenceField('Category', required=True)
    creation_date = mongo_db.DateTimeField()
```

And the following `model`, Resource defined for it:

```
post_fields = ns.model(
    'Post', 
    {
        'content': fields.String,
        'creation_date': fields.DateTime,
        'notes': fields.List(fields.String),
        'category': fields.Nested(category_fields),
        'URI': fields.Url('my_endpoint')
    }
)


class PostResource(Resource):

    @ns.marshal_with(post_fields)
    def get(self):
        queryset = Post.objects
        return list(queryset)
```

Everything works OK for all fields, except the fields.Url, and the following error is raised:

```
flask_restplus.fields.MarshallingError: url_for() argument after ** must be a mapping, not Post
```

I tried to use `flask`'s `jsonify` function:

```
return jsonify(queryset)
```

but the following error occur:

```
werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'my_endpoint' with values ['_on_close', '_status', '_status_code', 'direct_passthrough', 'headers', 'response']. Did you forget to specify values ['id']?
```

Please inform me if you want any other details, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I tried solving your problem by simplifying `Document` and `model`. The problem lies in response of your resource:

```
def get(self):
        queryset = Post.objects
        return list(queryset)
```

`queryset` becomes list of posts as `[<Post: Post object>, <Post: Post object>]`.
 When `marshal_with` decorator is applied to response, it [expects single object, dicts, or lists of objects](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fields.html#basic-usage). Although it should work with `Post` object, I'm not directly sure what causes error when applying  `URI` to `Post` object. It seems somehow that `url_for` method is called with it's proper arguments internally, and tries to unpack `Post` object as `**post`.

Small example:

```
def url_for(endpoint, *args, **kwargs):
    print(endpoint, args, kwargs)

class Post:

    def __init__(self):
        self.content = "Dummy content"

post1 = Post()  # Instance of Post class
post2 = {"content": "This dummy content works !"} # Dictionary

# This won't work, returns TypeError: url_for() argument after ** must be a mapping, not Post
url_for("my_endpoint", 1, 2, **post1)

# This works since it's able to unpack dictionary.
url_for("my_endpoint", 1, 2, **post2)
```

The solution is to convert every `Post` object to `dict` by using `.to_mongo().to_dict()` on it. Also, to represent URI of an object `Post` with ID, we must create resource route for it.

Full example:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restplus import Api, fields, Resource, marshal_with
from flask_mongoengine import MongoEngine

import uuid

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

app.config['MONGODB_SETTINGS'] = {
    'db': 'test',
    'host': 'localhost',
    'port': 27017
}

mongo_db = MongoEngine(app)

class Post(mongo_db.Document):
    id = mongo_db.UUIDField(max_length=300, required=True, primary_key=True)
    content = mongo_db.StringField(max_length=300, required=False)
    notes = mongo_db.ListField(mongo_db.StringField(max_length=2000), required=False)

#post1 = Post(id=uuid.uuid4(), content="abacdcad", notes=["a", "b"])
#post2 = Post(id=uuid.uuid4(), content="aaaaa", notes=["a", "bc"])

#post1.save()
#post2.save()

post_fields = {
    'content': fields.String,
    'notes': fields.List(fields.String),
    'URI': fields.Url('my_endpoint')
}

class PostResource(Resource):
    @marshal_with(post_fields)
    def get(self):
        queryset = [obj.to_mongo().to_dict() for obj in Post.objects]
        return queryset


class PostEndpoint(Resource):

    def get(self, _id):
        # Query db for this entry.
        return None


api.add_resource(PostResource, '/posts')
api.add_resource(PostEndpoint, '/post/<string:_id>', endpoint='my_endpoint')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Note above that `_id` represents `id` of entry in document. Mongoengine returns it like that, not sure why. Maybe primary key is represented with underscore in front of it.

Response of `http://127.0.0.1:5000/posts` should be (*URI is from my example here*):

```
[
  {
    "content": "Dummy content 1",
    "notes": [
      "a",
      "b"
    ],
    "URI": "/post/0b689467-41cc-4bb7-a606-881f6554a6b7"
  },
  {
    "content": "Dummy content 2",
    "notes": [
      "c",
      "d"
    ],
    "URI": "/post/8e8c1837-fdd2-4891-90cf-72edc0f4c19a"
  }
]
```

I hope this clears out the problem.

Comment: Thank you, but actually I already know that looping and converting each object manually resolve the problem(partially). But I am looking for a solution that allows me to get the benefits of flask-retplus `Model` and `marshaling` features, I do not want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: My Document are complex, and the code in the question are just exemplary to clarify the problem.

Comment: And I am converting the BaseQeury into list because flask-restplus has the following condition: `ininstance(data, (list, tuple))`, so it is check only for tuples and lists but not for any other iterable.

Comment: I'll try to add a solution without looping. Maybe it's flask problem on how it treats objects. I only simplified the model and document to for easier debugging. I think Flask-Mongoengine supports converting objects to dicts.

Comment: yes it support that, but it need some tweaking to handle object's ID.

Comment: Objects ID is represented as UUID. Do you need to include ID in response ? Or you are looking to way to skip over in response ?

Comment: I want to use the ID to generatea URI for a given object(Resource).

Comment: But how did you wantes to map ID to URI in response when all you do is return all posts ? In this case, you need some sort of util function. That is, to create dicionaries. Or at leasts to expand this dictionary with URI based on ID.

Comment: I want to return the URI of each Post object.

Comment: Check my edit. I understand now. This part, with URI represented as ID, was more of a second problem. The real question was about the problem with converting it to dict.